# Mysql to return count as 0 instead of nothing

Tags: mysql

I have seen the other questions here at stack but i am not able to solve my particular problem following is the example table

```
status area
a1     b1
a2     b1
a1     b2
```

following is the query i use

```
select count(*) as count, area, status from table group by area,status
```

which gives me

```
1 b1 a1
1 b1 a2
1 b2 a1
```

i want

```
0 b2 a2
```

also to be shown

i understand i have to use a join to do this so i tried the following

```
select Distinct(t1.status) as ds,t2.* from table as t1
right join
(select count(*), area, status from table group by area,status) t2
on t2.status=t1.status;
```

but this just gives me the same result without the 0

also tried this but apparently there is a syntax error i cant figure out

```
select t1.count,t2.ds,t1.area from
(select count(*) as count, area, status as ws from table group by area,status) t1
left join select distinct(status) as ds from table as t2
on t1.ws=t2.ds
```

Comment: If you want `0 b2 a2` to be shown, you will need a table to introduce this information, as it missing from your original source table.

Comment: As an aside, be aware that DISTINCT is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
SELECT COUNT(t.area) count, c_t.area, c_t.status 
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT status
      FROM table) t_status
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT area
        FROM table) t_area
     ) c_t
    LEFT JOIN table t 
     ON t.area = c_t.area
      AND t.status = c_t.status
GROUP BY c_t.area, c_t.status;
```

Hope this should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim pointed out in his comment: you need to introduce the missing record somehow, mysql will not be able to figure it out on its own.

What you can do is to create a cartesian join between status and area values using a self join, then left join the original table again on this and do the group by and count:

```
select t1.status, t2.area, count(t3.status)
from (select distinct status from yourtable) t1
     join (select distinct area from yourtable) t2
     left join yourtable t3 on t3.status=t1.status and t3.area=t2.area
group by t1.status, t2.area
```

Answer (score 0):

The `COUNT()` function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criteria. That means that the **smallest result** of it will be zero by definition - i.e. `COUNT()` cannot return "*nothing*".